# Converting Firebase Datasnapshot to codable JSON data

Tags: json, swift, firebase, codable

I'm using Firebase Database and I'm attempting to retrieve and use data with `NSObject`. I'm receiving an `NSUnknownKeyException` error when running the app, causing it to crash.

NSObject:

```
class WatchList: NSObject {

    var filmid: Int?

}
```

Firebase Code:

```swift
ref.child("users").child(uid!).child("watchlist").observe(DataEventType.childAdded, with: { (info) in
    print(info)
    
    if let dict = info.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let list = WatchList()
        list.setValuesForKeys(dict)
        print(list)
    }        
}, withCancel: nil)
```

I'm not sure of what could cause this.

Also, to enhance this solution is their a way to take this data and, instead of using NSObject, use `Codable` and `JSONDecoder` with the Firebase data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### It's 2021 now.

Firebase finally added support for decoding Firestore documents. Just let your objects conform to `Codable` and decode like this:

```
let result = Result {
  try document?.data(as: City.self)
}
switch result {
case .success(let city):
    if let city = city {
        print("City: \(city)")
    } else {
        print("Document does not exist")
    }
case .failure(let error):
    // A `City` value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
    print("Error decoding city: \(error)")
}
```

Just don't forget to add the `'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'` pod and then import it into your file.

Read more:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#custom_objects

**Original answer**

A really nice library to use here is [Codable Firebase](https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase) which I am also using in my project. Just make your class / struct conform to `Codable` protocol and use FirebaseDecoder to decode your Firebase data into a Swift object.

Example:

```
Database.database().reference().child("model").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    guard let value = snapshot.value else { return }
    do {
        let model = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(Model.self, from: value)
        print(model)
    } catch let error {
        print(error)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 9):

You can simply use JSONSerialization to convert the snapshot value property from `Any` to `Data`:

```
let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: snapshot.value)
```

You can also extend Firebase DataSnapshot type and add a data and json string properties to it:

```
import Firebase 

extension DataSnapshot {
    var data: Data? {
        guard let value = value, !(value is NSNull) else { return nil }
        return try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value)
    }
    var json: String? { data?.string }
}
extension Data {
    var string: String? { String(data: self, encoding: .utf8) }
}
```

---

usage:

```
guard let data = snapshot.data else { return }
```