# Is there a way to compress this if->cast line?

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a Dictionary<String,Any> as my source data.

I have an object that isn't playing nice with Codable (it's an ObservableObject and it seems @Published props break Codable).

So I'm doing the following (simplified example) in a function.

```
    var rtn = TheObjectInQuestion()

    if let _pid = dict["p_id"] as? String { rtn.pId = _pid }
    if let _active = dict["active"] as? Int { rtn.active = _active }

    return rtn
```

What I'm wondering is, am I missing a shorter / simpler way to do a bunch of the if->let->cast lines against the object from the dictionary?

No worries if not; this is certainly clear and readable enough as it is. Just a little tedious.

Thanks!

Comment: Get away from the `[String: Any]`. Work on the "isn't playing nice with Codable" part. Convert this to a struct or class and the issues will go away. If you're having trouble with that; ask that question. There's no way to make a `[String: Any]` a nice type to work with. Typically you'd use a Codable struct, and have the ObservableObject hold onto that (or initialize from it).

Comment: The data is coming from a Firebase data store over which I have no control, and fetching it gives me a bunch of nulls if there's no data, so the optionals (which are a pain the butt) and the String/Any just kind of happens. I have to deal with that somewhere, and in this case, I'm trying to just spin up my object right away. I honestly hadn't thought of wrapping the Codable inside the Observable rather than trying to make it the same object. Interesting. Thanks.

Comment: To clarify, when I said "the optionals just kind of happen" I meant I had to make pretty much everything in my Codable class optional (only 3 of the ~19 fields are guaranteed to not be null in this data), and that just seems sloppy and lazy. Beyond that, I really love your suggestion of wrapping the codable in an Observable. ! Thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisH https://stackoverflow.com/a/54040528/2303865

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest moving this conversion into an initializer, something along these lines:

```
struct TheObjectInQuestion {
    let pId: String?
    let active: Int

    init(from dict: [String: Any]) {
        self.pId = dict["p_id"] as? String // keep optional
        self.active = dict["active"] as? Int ?? 0 // use default value
    }
}
```

This has the advantage of allowing you to say `let obj = TheObjectInQuestion(from: dict)` (instead of `var` everywhere), and you can have a single place where you assign default values if the individual properties can't be Optionals.

There's really no good way to get around the line-by-line treatment of these properties and their mapping to the dictionary keys, unfortunately.

Comment: I like that. Way leaner, and not sure why I didn't go that extra step to chop it down a little bit more. That really makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that works like a charm, adding ?? ""  or ?? 0 where applicable. Thanks!